# When child array updates UI does not refresh in knockout js

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I am working on knockout js. I have an observable array object like

viewModel () {

```
self.myObservableArray = ko.observableArray();


}
```

After some asyc api call, I will update the array like this

```
self.myObservableArray().push({
    "name" : "Some name",
    "childArray" : []
});
```

After second aync api call, I will have to loop through the response and push an item inside childArray in each loop.

```
self.myObservableArray()[0]. childArray.push({
        "childName" : "name " + $index
    })
```

But UI does not refresh as I updating second level array. What is the correct way to add elements so UI refreshes or atleast is there a way to trigger the event that says parent property is changed.

Comment: Did my answer help you resolve your issue? if so, please mark my answer as accepted by ticking the V symbol to its left. If not, let me know and I'll try to further help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the UI to be updated when `childArray` is changed, then it needs to be an `observableArray` as well. I also guess you'd need to make `name` an observable, too, so might be a good idea to just tie them both in a separate view model, for example:

```
var childViewModel = function (name, items) {
   var self = this;
   self.name = ko.observable(name);
   self.childArray = ko.observableArray(items);
}

self.myObservableArray.push(new childViewMode("Some name", []));
```